# Is the weighted average of growth rates equal to the growth rate of a weighted average?

Tags: time-series, mean, weights, weighted-mean

More formally, is the following statement true? Let $\alpha$ be between 0 and 1.

\begin{equation}
\alpha\frac{(A_t - A_{t-1})}{A_{t-1}}\ + (1-\alpha)\frac{(B_t - B_{t-1})}{B_{t-1}}= \frac{(\alpha A_t + (1-\alpha)B_t)-(\alpha A_{t-1} + (1-\alpha)B_{t-1})}{(\alpha A_{t-1} + (1-\alpha)B_{t-1})} 
\end{equation}

If it is not true, is it possible to determine how much they differ by?

Comment: To investigate whether this is true, something you could do is just plug in some numbers and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah I see it now, thank you for reminding me!